# how to create dynamic pivot tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, pivot, pivot-table, crosstab

I'm having trouble generating pivot tables in MySQL and wonder if anyone can give me any tips and some documentation so I can finally resolve this problem.

My problem is as follows:

I have 2 tables in my database.  `clients` contains customer information such as name, ssn and some personal data.  In the `cli_location` table are client locations: address, telephone number, mobile phone and so on.

Sometimes we need to do selects based on criteria such as location, to pick up customers in a particular city.  We also make queries based on cpf to get information for a specific customer.

I often need to cross these two tables.  I currently do a `left join`. The problem with the `left join` is that sometimes the client has more than one phone, which generates new lines for each one.

When researching how to improve this behavior I discovered pivot tables, however I am not able to understand them.

## 1st table (clients):

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╦════════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ id ║ name ║  ssn  ║  dt_birth  ║ store ║ value  ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ john ║ 12345 ║ 1991-11-04 ║   318 ║ 34.33  ║
║  2 ║ john ║ 12345 ║ 1991-11-04 ║   318 ║ 654.44 ║
║  3 ║ john ║ 12345 ║ 1991-11-04 ║   212 ║ 238.00 ║
║  4 ║ alex ║ 54321 ║ 1988-05-20 ║   321 ║ 334.44 ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╩════════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

## 2st table(cli_location):

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╦══════════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ name ║  ssn  ║ address  ║  city  ║  state  ║  zip  ║   tel    ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ john ║ 12345 ║ street1  ║ city1  ║ state1  ║ 23443 ║ 23432122 ║
║  2 ║ john ║ 12345 ║ street1  ║ city1  ║ state1  ║ 23443 ║ 98765434 ║
║  3 ║ john ║ 12345 ║ street2  ║ city5  ║ state7  ║ 54323 ║ 65765567 ║
║  4 ║ john ║ 12345 ║ street3  ║ city4  ║ state9  ║ 76543 ║ 44323455 ║
║  5 ║ alex ║ 54321 ║ street34 ║ city30 ║ state33 ║ 43234 ║ 86643457 ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╩══════════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

When crossing the tables using left join, with the field of reference being `ssn`, the result has many duplicate lines.  I am not able to change the structure of the data in production.

I had thought about doing something like :

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╦════════════╦═══════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦══════════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════╦══════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦══════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ name ║  ssn  ║  dt_birth  ║ store ║ value  ║ store1 ║ value1 ║ store2 ║ value2 ║ address  ║  city  ║  state  ║  zip  ║ address1 ║ city1  ║ state1 ║  zip1  ║ address2 ║ city2  ║ state2 ║  zip2  ║   tel    ║   tel1   ║   tel2   ║   tel3   ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬══════════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ john ║ 12345 ║ 1991-11-04 ║   318 ║ 34.33  ║ 318    ║ 654.44 ║ 212    ║ 238.00 ║ street1  ║ city1  ║ state1  ║ 23443 ║ street2  ║ city5  ║ state7 ║ 54323  ║ street3  ║ city4  ║ state9 ║ 76543  ║ 23432122 ║ 98765434 ║ 65765567 ║ 44323455 ║
║  4 ║ alex ║ 54321 ║ 1988-05-20 ║   321 ║ 334.33 ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ street34 ║ city30 ║ state33 ║ 43234 ║ (null)   ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null)   ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null)   ║ 86643457 ║ (null)   ║ (null)   ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╩════════════╩═══════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩══════════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════╩══════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩══════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

The idea is to generate columns dynamically as there are more lines with the same type of information, as in the above table.  Even if there are 2 rows with the same `store`, the value of field `value` differs so columns must be added for each `store`-`value` pair.  The same for the `address` and `phone` fields as in the table above.

If someone could point me to some documentation, show me any examples or anything that helps me learn how to do this kind of thing I would be very grateful!

Comment: What sort of thing did google throw up?

Comment: @Strawberry, All I found on google about talking about prepared statements I tried to adapt my need and could not because all the items I have seen apparently know the value to consider in the field to generate a new column, here I have no way of knowing the amount of phones and "stores" with different field "value" in each row. I found some people talking about what is possible with prepared statements create these "dynamical" fields just do not understand how. Can you help me?

Comment: "Prepared statements"? But I thought this was a question about "creating pivot table queries dynamically in MySQL"?

Comment: @Strawberry, is really a question about how to generate pivot tables in mysql as I explained in the question above. I mentioned the prepared statements that was what I found in my research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

Thinking about this further, I'm confident that SQL can not do exactly what you need.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977988/701303) explains why, and lists your choices:

1. write application code to build a query dynamically, or
2. run your existing `left join` query, and then write application code to manipulate the result into the desired format.

**However**, if you're comfortable combining multiple values into one column, `group_concat` might get you close:

```
select
  ssn,
  name,
  group_concat(distinct tel separator ', ') phones,
  group_concat(distinct address separator '; ') addresses
from
  (select clients.ssn,
    clients.name,
    cli_location.tel,
    concat(cli_location.address, ', ', city, ' ', zip) address
  from clients 
  left join cli_location
    on clients.ssn=cli_location.ssn) c
group by ssn
```

produces:

```
|   SSN | NAME |                                 PHONES |                                                        ADDRESSES |
|-------|------|----------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 12345 | john | 23432122, 44323455, 65765567, 98765434 | street1, city1 23443; street3, city4 76543; street2, city5 54323 |
| 54321 | alex |                               86643457 |                                           street34, city30 43234 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca287/25

### Original

If you want a list of customers in a particular city:

```
select clients.ssn, clients.name
from clients
inner join cli_location
  using(ssn)
where city = 'city1'
group by ssn;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca287/3

Your schema is making this more difficult than it should be though.  Consider normalizing it so that client names are in only one table, and split one-to-many relationships (like client:phone) into separate tables.

Comment: Hello, fivenine I think you misunderstand what I need. I need all the results of an inner join cliente.O not satisfy my need because I need to bring up the result when no address data in the database. Both left join inner join as i see add line:  
look: http://goo.gl/hP69y4 look: http://goo.gl/29pPa9
these two cases and used the left inner join to bring a result that I need. note that it doubled some values ​​and increased the number of lines. what I need is to bring this result only in one row without these duplications as happened with the phone field understand? anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: sqlfiddle is down right now so I can't see your examples, but I think I understand anyway.  I don't know how do what you are looking for.  It might not be possible with SQL alone.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i will follow your advice. I thought about going down this road a few days ago but i heard about pivot tables and thought it might be a better outlet since I often do I export the data to a csv file ... but again thanks for you help!