# How to create horizontal columns from rows in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

Sorry if I asked this dumb question as it puzzled me how to do such for several days.

I have a table in MySQL named Grades.
[image]

Now, what I want to do is to make an output like this one.
[image]

Is there an SQL to do such? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL - Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Comment: See also my answer to [MySQL dynamic cross tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977855/mysql-dynamic-cross-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a case/when and group by the student and the class.  If you want only a single person, just apply a where clause... or even if you want all students for a class, or a given school year... etc.

```
SELECT
      g.studNumber,
      g.subjCode,
      MAX( case when g.period = 1 then g.grade else 0 end ) as 1st_period,
      MAX( case when g.period = 2 then g.grade else 0 end ) as 2nd_period,
      MAX( case when g.period = 3 then g.grade else 0 end ) as 3rd_period,
      MAX( case when g.period = 4 then g.grade else 0 end ) as 4th_period,
      AVG( g.grade ) as Ave
   from
      Grades g
   group by 
      g.studNumber,
      g.subjCode
```

Comment: Thank you so much Drapp for your help... this SQL statement works. Im so grateful for you.