# Is it possible to add a while loop in a mysql select query?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I'm a mysql newbie and I'm trying to find a better way to write the following query. Is there any way to include a while loop in a select query? I have attempted to use a while loop as well as a stored procedure with no luck. I would prefer not to use a stored procedure if at all possible. Can someone help me?

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( contactdata, '";', 2)
  , ':"', -1) as Cadet_Name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 1) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '1',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 2) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '2',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 3) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '3',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 4) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '4',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 5) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '5',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 6) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '6',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 7) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '7',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 8) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '8',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 9) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '9',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 10) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '10',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 11) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '11',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 12) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '12',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 13) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '13',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 14) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '14',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 15) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '15',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 16) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '16',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 17) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '17',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 18) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '18',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 19) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '19',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 20) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '20',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 21) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '21',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 22) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '22',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 23) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '23',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 24) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '24',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 25) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '25',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 26) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '26',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 27) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '27',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 28) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '28',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 29) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '29',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 30) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '30',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 31) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '31',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 32) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '32',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 33) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '33',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 34) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '34',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 35) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '35',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 36) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '36',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 37) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '37',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 38) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '38',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 39) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '39',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 40) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '40',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 41) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '41',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 42) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '42',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 43) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '43',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 44) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '44',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 45) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '45',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 46) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '46',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 47) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '47',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 48) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '48',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 49) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '49',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 50) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '50',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 51) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '51',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 52) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '52',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 53) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '53',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 54) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '54',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 55) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '55',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 56) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '56',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 57) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '57',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 58) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '58',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 59) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '59',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 60) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '60',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 61) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '61',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 62) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '62',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 63) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '63',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 64) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '64',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 65) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '65',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 66) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '66',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 67) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '67',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 68) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '68',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 69) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '69',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 70) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '70',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 71) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '71',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 72) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '72',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 73) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '73',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 74) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '74',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 75) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '75',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 76) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '76',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 77) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '77',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 78) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '78',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 79) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '79',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 80) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '80',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 81) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '81',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 82) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '82',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 83) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '83',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 84) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '84',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 85) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '85',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 86) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '86',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 87) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '87',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 88) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '88',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 89) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '89',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 90) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '90',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 91) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '91',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 92) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '92',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 93) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '93',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 94) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '94',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 95) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '95',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 96) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '96',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 97) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '97',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 98) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '98',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 99) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '99',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 100) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '100',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 101) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '101',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 102) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '102',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 103) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '103',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 104) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '104',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 105) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '105',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 106) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '106',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 107) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '107',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 108) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '108',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 109) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '109',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 110) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '110',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 111) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '111',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 112) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '112',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 113) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '113',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 114) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '114',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 115) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '115',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 116) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '116',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 117) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '117',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 118) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '118',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 119) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '119',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 120) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '120',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 121) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '121',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 122) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '122',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 123) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '123',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 124) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '124',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 125) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '125',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 126) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '126',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 127) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '127',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 128) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '128',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 129) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '129',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 130) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '130',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 131) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '131',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 132) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '132',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 133) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '133',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 134) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '134',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 135) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '135',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 136) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '136',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 137) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '137',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 138) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '138',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 139) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '139',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 140) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '140',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 141) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '141',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 142) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '142',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 143) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '143',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 144) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '144',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 145) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '145',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 146) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '146',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 147) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '147',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 148) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '148',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 149) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '149',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 150) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '150',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 151) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '151',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 152) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '152',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 153) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '153',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 154) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '154',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 155) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '155',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 156) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '156',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 157) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '157',
MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 158) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '158',
  GROUP_CONCAT(QuestionId,'-',AnswerId ORDER BY QuestionId) AS Question_Answer
  FROM wp_dzfy2v_quiz_users
  INNER JOIN wp_dzfy2v_quiz_users_answers
  ON wp_dzfy2v_quiz_users_answers.UserId = wp_dzfy2v_quiz_users.Id
  WHERE contactdata != 'a:0:{}'
  GROUP BY UserId
```

Comment: You cannot put any looping code into an sql query. What is the problem you are trying to solve by looping?

Comment: @SamM Thank you for the reply. I'm trying to consolidate the lines of code similar to the following: 'MAX(CASE WHEN (QuestionId = 31) THEN AnswerId ELSE NULL END) AS '31' Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: A better way is to handle problems of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL requires that all the columns of the query's select-list are specified at the time you submit the query. You can't make a query that dynamically expands its columns based on what it finds in the database.

In general, when you write a pivot-table query like the one you show, you do it in multiple steps:

1. Decide (or query) how many distinct columns you want your query to show
2. Construct a custom query, based on what you discover
3. Run the custom query

You should write application code to do these steps. See an example in an old answer of mine: [MySQL dynamic cross tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977855/mysql-dynamic-cross-tab/8977988#8977988)

SQL is not a language you can use alone. You should use it in combination with some application code language.

Comment: Thanks for the info!